# Why can my main class not see its main method?

Tags: java, class, package, program-entry-point

In my MergeSortMini Program my main class cannot see or load its main method. I dont declare the mergesortmini package above the main class, but this did not cause a problem in another program where my code runs fine without a package decleration.

This is my main class in my MergeSortMini program (This does not run):

```
class MergeSortMini {
    public static void main(String[] a){
        MergeSort m = new MergeSort();
        m.init().sort().printData();
    }
}
```

This is my main class in my MergeSortProgram (This does run):

```
class MergeSortTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MergeSort m = new MergeSort();
        m.init().sort().printData();  
    }
}
```

why can one program see its main method without a package and another can't?

Additional info: My project specifies that I cannot use package declerations.

Comment: What are the file names?

Comment: Are MergeSortMini.java and MergeSortTest.java and MergeSort.java ALL in the same directory?

Comment: That is one weird project specification

Comment: Try adding a `public` modifier in front of the class declaration: `public class MergeSortMini`...

Comment: MergeSortMini and MergeSortTest are in different directories. And I tried adding a public modifier, the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

One possible response is that the "MergeSortTest" is in the same packaged that the "MergeSort" class.

If the "MergeSortMini" class is in a different packaged it will not recognised the "MergeSort" class.

Regards,

Comment: No MergeSortMini is sturcturally identical to MergeSortTest.